# File upload in AngularJS causes browser out of memory error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, out-of-memory

I have an AngularJS code to perform upload of files. At first I thought it works OK but when I've tried to upload bigger files (e.g. 5 files, 10 MB each) then I saw that this code has very poor performance regarding memory handling.

For example: when I attach 5 files (10 MB each = 50 MB in total) then peak browser process memory demand reaches 2 GB!
I've tested it in Firefox, Chrome and IE. Additionally, in Chrome when browser process reaches 3 GB of memory committed then the page crashes.
In Firefox I can see an error in console when trying to upload more than 80 MB at once: 
`out of memory`

I've tried to modify the parts where the actual request is made and removed `data: JSON.stringify(formattedData)` which was the first bottleneck. And it turned out that `stringify`ing is redundant there.

But the second bottleneck still exists which is the function `binArrayToJson` which takes the ArrayBuffer and reads the data into the byte array.

```
var binArrayToJson = function (binArray) {
   var str = [binArray.length];
   for (var i = 0, binLength = binArray.length; i < binLength; i++) {
   str[i] = binArray[i];
   }
   return str;
}

var applyAttachments = function (data1) {
   angular.forEach(data1,
       function (value, key) {
           if (key === "Attachments") {
               for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                   if (value[i].file) { //already saved item don't contain 'file' property
                       var reader = new FileReader();

                       reader.onloadend = (function (f) {
                           return function (result) {

                               var arrayBuffer = result.target.result;
                               value[f].fileContent = binArrayToJson(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
                               value[f].isUploaded = true;
                           };
                       })(i);

                       reader.readAsArrayBuffer(value[i].file);
                   }
               }
           }
       });
};


var createMVCModel = function (output) {
   var defaultStringValue = "";
   return {
       id: output.id,
       Name: output.name || defaultStringValue,
       Status: output.status || "Draft",
       Date: output.date || null
       Attachments: output.attachments || []
   };
};

var saveModel = function (data, url) {
   var formattedData = createMVCModel(data);
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   applyAttachments(formattedData);

   var check = function () {
       if (allNewFilesUploaded(formattedData) === true) {
           $http({
                   url: url,
                   method: "POST",
                   data: formattedData,
                   headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
               })
               .then(function (result) {
                       deferred.resolve(result);
                   },
                   function (result) {
                       deferred.reject(result);
                   });
       } else {
           setTimeout(check, 1000);
       }

   }
   check();
   return deferred.promise;
};
```

I omitted the parts where the following requirements are being met:

- checking number of files (limit is 10)
- checking size of each file (limit is 10 MB each)
- checking permitted file extensions
- sending rest of the (text) data along with files to the server (ASP.NET MVC method)

Comment: It's a bad idea to send files as json... use multipart upload (ie. [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/API/FormData))

Comment: With the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/API/FormData), the [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` adds an extra 33% overhead. If the server supports it, **it is more efficient to send the files directly.**

Answer (score 0):

### Doing Multiple `$http.post` Requests Directly from a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)

To avoid memory problems, **send the files directly:**

```
$scope.upload = function(url, fileList) {
    var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                   transformResponse: angular.identity
                 };
    var promises = fileList.map(function(file,index) {
        config.params = {'n': index, 'name': file.name};
        return $http.post(url, file, config);
    });
    return $q.all(promises);
};
```

When sending a POST with a [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), it is important to set `'Content-Type': undefined`. The [XHR send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) will then detect the [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and automatically set the content type.